# Microsoft Teams Change iFrame Permissions

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm embedding a 3rd party video solution (Vimeo) in an iFrame inside my app using the following code.

```
<iframe
        title="unique-id"
        sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-presentation"
        ref={iframeRef}
        src={srcLink}
        allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
        allowFullScreen
        className={clsx('absolute h-full w-full', { 'blur-sm': isEnded })}
      ></iframe>
```

When I run my app in Teams, the console spits out `DOMException: Failed to construct 'PresentationRequest': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-presentation' flag` which tells the iFrame that Teams's using to wrap my own app doesn't have the 'allow-presentation' flag.

Is there a way for me to set the permission of the iFrame that Teams uses to show my app?

Also, there is another problem that might not be related to the above question. When I try to click the play button within the iFrame that's embedded by my app, the console prints out `NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`, is there a way to avoid this from happening (i.e. is there a way for me to interact with the Teams's iFrame to avoid this error?

Comment: Could you please refer this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API and `NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first` error occurs due to browser security restrictions that prevent media playback without user interaction. Browsers require user interaction, such as a click or touch event, before allowing media playback to prevent autoplaying media that may be disruptive or unwanted. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the `play()` method is called in response to a user interaction event, such as a button click.